# How to get rid of the home link in nav menu?

Tags: menus, navigation

I am using the following code for my navigation structure. Currently it shows a home link in the navigation. Why does this show? and how would I get rid of it by changing this code.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location'=> 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

it shows the home link cause you don't have anything set yet...

go to your functions.php and add this code

```
 add_theme_support( 'menus' );
  if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
          'header_menu' => 'Header Menu'
        )
    );

}

endif;
```

Go to Apparence and then get into Menu option... Create a menu set the pages/links/categories or whatever you want on it. Make sure you set the menu you just created in the dropdown list you have on top left in that panel. That should be enough to call the menu you want where you set the code you have.